# Crear trigger en sql server para que al insertar un artículo nuevo, ese artículo se cargue en otra tabla con su correspondiente precio

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, update

Bueno el trigger es de inserción y de modificación, al ingresar un artículo nuevo a la tabla este artículo debe agregarse en otra tabla con su respectivo precio.Y si se modifica el precio de algun artículo, al igual que el anterior debe agregarse a la nueva tabla.

Answer (score 0):

ya logre crear un trigger que cuando modifique algun dato en los precios de los articulos, me los pase a otra tabla. Ahora me falta hacer de que si al insertar un articulo nuevo en la tabla articulos, me lo pase a la otra tabla. dejo el codigo de ambos triggers, los hice por separado aunque deberia hacerlos en un mismo trigger.

create trigger tr_log_precios On
articulos
after update
AS
Begin
IF (UPDATE(preciomenor))
insert into LOG_PRECIOS (Articulo,Tipo,Valor_ant,Valor_nvo,Usuario,Equipo,FechaHora)
select i.articulo,'PME',d.preciomenor,i.preciomenor,'User',12,GETDATE()
FRom inserted i, deleted d

```
IF (UPDATE(preciomayor))
    insert into LOG_PRECIOS (Articulo,Tipo,Valor_ant,Valor_nvo,Usuario,Equipo,FechaHora)
        select i.articulo,'PMO',d.preciomayor,i.preciomayor,'User',12,GETDATE()
        FRom inserted i, deleted d
        
    IF (UPDATE(preciocosto))
    insert into LOG_PRECIOS (Articulo,Tipo,Valor_ant,Valor_nvo,Usuario,Equipo,FechaHora)
        select i.articulo,'PCO',d.preciocosto,i.preciocosto,'User',12,GETDATE()
        FRom inserted i, deleted d
        end
```

create trigger insertar_log_precios on
articulos
after insert
AS
begin
IF (NOT EXISTS (select articulo from articulos))
insert into LOG_PRECIOS
select i.articulo, 'PMO', null, i.preciomayor,'Usuario',13,GETDATE()
from inserted i, deleted d
end